# Installing Windows 10 without USB with ubuntu 18.04: this is not a bootable disk error

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2

I've found on google a way to install Windows 10 without an USB/DVD by copying the installer to a second partition and make it bootable. I've managed to do that and update my grub but when I'm trying to boot into the new partition this error comes up: `This is not a bootable disk please insert a bootable floppy`.

Is there any way to install Windows 10 using this way or I should give up? Notice that I can't buy an USB at the moment.

Here's my grub menu-entry for the windows setup:

```
menuentry 'Windows Recovery Environment (on /dev/sda4)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-592C85254E2CD0B7' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='hd0,msdos4'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos4 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos4 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos4  592C85254E2CD0B7
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 592C85254E2CD0B7
    fi
    parttool ${root} hidden-
    drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
    chainloader +1
}
```

Comment: Fixed by updating my grub.cfg and adding ntldr /bootmgr

Comment: Marcel Alexandru: I tried your method, adding `ntldr /bootmgr` on the line after `chainloader +1`, I also changed `hd0,msdos4` and the UUID in the above menuentry in my grub.cfg, to suit my disk. I then created a 6GB NTFS partition and extracted a Windows 10 ISO to it, (Windows-1909.iso). It worked like a charm. Please post your answer as an aid to other people with the same question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Installing Windows 10 without USB using Ubuntu, Step by Step

This step by step has been created from information provided by the OP, @Marcel Alexandru.

- Backup the Target drive.
- Create a 6GB NTFS partition on the hard drive and extract the Windows ISO to it.
- Create a 20GB, or larger, NTFS partition on the hard drive for the Windows Installation.
- Open Disks, (Gnome-Disks), and note Device, (/dev/sdx), and UUID of the Windows ISO extract partition.
- For msdos partition table, copy the menuentry given in this question to `/etc/grub.d/40-custom/`*
- Add `ntldr /bootmgr` as a line below `chainloader +1`
- Edit menuentry, changing `sda4 to sdax`, `msdos4` to `msdosx` (4 places), and 592C85254E2CD0B7 to UUID, (3 places), to suit step 4 above.
- Run `sudo update grub` confirm that `ntldr /bootmgr` appears in grub.cfg.
- Boot the computer into the newly created menuentry and install Windows into it's new partition.
- Reinstall Ubuntu if desired, the GRUB bootloader will have been replaced with the Windows bootloader.

*Note from the OP: You don't have to reinstall Ubuntu to fix the grub loader. You can boot in the Ubuntu Live USB, open a terminal and open Boot Repair using the `boot-repair` command. If it's not available you can install it using the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

For more information about repairing your Grub follow this link: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair.

*For gpt partition table, copy the following menuentry to `/etc/grub.d/40-custom/`:

```
menuentry 'Windows Recovery Environment (on /dev/sdc1)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-5642BC722509341F' {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ntfs
    set root='hd0,gpt1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt1  5642BC722509341F
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 5642BC722509341F
    fi
    drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
    chainloader +1
    ntldr /bootmgr
}
```

This method can also be adjusted to make a Windows installer USB or to add a Windows installer to a multiboot USB.

**Limitations**

Windows 10 has limitations with respect to partition tables and boot modes.

I was able to install Legacy mode Windows to a drive with a MSDOS partition table.

I was able to install UEFI mode Windows to a drive with a GPT partition table.

I was not able to install Legacy mode Windows to a drive with a GPT partition table.

I was not able to install UEFI mode Windows to a drive with a GPT partition table and Legacy mode Ubuntu.

There may be workarounds that are outside the scope of this answer.

Comment: @Marcel Alexandru: You are welcome to use any or all of my answer in your answer. I will remove my answer after you have posted.

Comment: I forgot about this question lol. It was 2AM when I asked it. Thanks for making a proper answer. Btw, don't forget about the `insmod ntldr` line. It isn't generated by the `update-grub` command

Comment: @Marcel Alexandru grub.cfg was updated just as I entered it into /etc/grub.d/40_custom however I have added a notein the answer to confirm grub.cfg. Thank you.

Comment: Btw, your question explains everything it needs to be done, you can remove the "Please don't upvote this answer" if you want :)

Comment: I added a note on how to repair Grub without reinstalling Ubuntu. We just need to wait for approval

Comment: @Yash: Your answer has reminded me of the requirements that Windows 10 has for installation on MSDOS and GPT partitions tables. Thank you very much. I will probably add a note to this answer after I have confirmed them by trial and error. If you wish to contact me, I can be PM'd at Ubuntu Forums.