# Multicolored screen when trying to boot from a Windows installation USB

Tags: boot, system-installation, live-usb, windows-10, visual-artifacts

I've been trying to replace my Ubuntu OS with Windows. I have created a bootable Windows installation USB. First I created the disk using Windows Media Creation Tool on Windows, and I get this screen when I boot from USB. Then I also tried creating the USB from an ISO file using WoeUSB on Ubuntu and I still get the same screen when I boot from the USB.

[image: Multicolored screen when trying to boot from windows USB]

Comment: Try mkusb-plug: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1274878/make-windows-10-bootable-usb-in-ubuntu/1274975#1274975,  or mkusb-dus or see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284364/installing-windows-10-without-usb-with-ubuntu-18-04-this-is-not-a-bootable-disk/1284712?noredirect=1#comment2180033_1284712 WoeUSB does not work for me either.

Answer (score 1):

try this with https://www.balena.io/etcher/, let me know if it is working for you.