# Switching back to Windows 10

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, windows-10

Selling a PC that is currently running Ubuntu. I need to switch back to windows 10 for the buyer. It previously had windows 10 installed. I downloaded the windows 10 iso file,and copied all of the files to a formatted USB drive. I have rebooted from the USB drive, but I dont think its working. I installed unetbootin to make a bootable USB drive that way, but i cannot find the iso file in unetbootin. It was difficult to find the iso file just to copy it to the USB drive manually, i had to find its location through the internet browser i used to download the file, but i cannot find it from my desktop. When I can find it, there is a "lock" icon over the file, im not sure if that is relevant as I am pretty bad with computers.
How can I re-install windows and get rid of Ubuntu the easiest way? I dont care what happens to any of my data.

Comment: UNetbootin does not do Windows. In Ubuntu Try mkusb or Ventoy.or see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284364/installing-windows-10-without-usb-with-ubuntu-18-04-this-is-not-a-bootable-disk/1284712#1284712

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get Windows to boot from a USB thumb drive using Unetbootin.  I had to use Rufus to create the USB drive instead.

https://rufus.ie/